# Rare AADSTS7000215 error from Microsoft (Invalid client secret is provided)

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, azure-webapps, microsoft-identity-platform

Sometimes on trying to obtain token on:

```
login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

I receive the error:

```
AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided
```

I am sure that client_secret is correct and not expired. Most of the requests with the same client_secret are successful, but some of them return this error.

What can be the reason for such behavior?

Request body:

```
{'request': {
    'redirect_uri': u'',
    'client_id': 'MASKED',
    'client_secret': u'MASKED',
    'scope': u'profile openid https://outlook.office.com/Contacts.Read https://outlook.office.com/Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared https://outlook.office.com/Calendars.ReadWrite https://outlook.office.com/Mail.ReadWrite offline_access https://outlook.office.com/Mail.Send email',
    'grant_type': u'refresh_token',
    'refresh_token': 'OAQABAAAAAAAm-06blBE1TpMVil8KPQ419Zing5ASwdVVebcvJ2_pcAkVb6Pj-XFOjx7E1BxzGNgdj7IGLEPjXn74srIqSLoNWJ-QAw_CTIknISEQnuAV1-5lkh97OS-i-lSa3tLauMnpgX6r-xG-5ETMxDZT4FEffPsm3iUJyvPVTCViLOm7Bbo1jnY0bS69zHKee5q4GDRXGF5zwI48_JhFGUoyyIY-Nb6CXuBg3DTC5s0Ntq3j-A_a4LVkXwYANiUmsULK8HuqDK8Obd69_RdulDeGGAkXXcds3JFBN469qhA3WD0_9UP10Zr3UZ9iKV4pbTX87lR9k8TFhu4HcJ490vpwgKefLFMqmsaJOcaSE5llg9l691X0zXh8-bcgK2ARWeDL62nkW18mDHr9R-tGvzmtpb-zjVVGGEBGMHhkZH-eH87yo5olmJZttEPaKcK_6orxR7hKm_0TXkkcYIhQreR6_s1B-a1TS3wxA10IuW7ueTuOXg6-lsXSZAZzMJ-jPk1f0nbO9IbNYYlvx_LgvC17JaU7w-8JfrxHZuiShsloPyvTbnicsfwj7_OuLR-cX3cULyPn4B9BSJkNV3289NFT0R_F7GP-0hhoKydbc0z7pq4v1QLkdsQ4ar_23GLiwh2LYFH1mO2BlYPrLI2lrB0-b7u2yJvvm96w6L-dCr_nvJtK9e1nb1NCRQBIhuJaPzc-mRXdGZAGquOfsSl_tyYNQdUq_PFfCR7Yezy4FFdOks9w9Gx3lCrr9v9SV4m9Z4ULsyu3lmxjLWuTt_cXex-d-cMbmMfeNJ_2NEuUmlsjtV--2vBG209-batKzl6fMPZLCjDrRit5IpeBNt6vzaI0f-1na0XPtpm9voiZsaFgD0IWY9O-x9nU0JAtgekiq4xn3RaU79ICjndwHUr3SOeizOpbIAA'
}}
```

Comment: Please show the request body.

Comment: @JoyWang added to description

Answer (score 0):

I've been in the same situation.

This was resolved by resetting the service principal.

[az ad sp credential | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp/credential?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-credential-reset)